# What is the MinValue of DateTime in CRM2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

CRM 4.0 has the type CRMDateTime with a MinValue= 1.1.1900, whereas CRM2011 suppports native types for DateTime.

We need to set dates older than 1.1.1900 and I wonder if this is possible with CRM2011.

What is the DateTime.MinValue in CRM2011?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's also 1900-01-01 if you try to load data via the API. It's not a GUI limitation but a system limitation.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I would suggest that the oldest value you can store is limited by SQL Server which is theoretically '1753-01-01'</strike>

It is still 1900-01-01 in the GUI. If you try to set a date any further in the past than this it gives you an out of range error.

Comment: I just had the chance to test this in the CRM2011 GUI,and you are correct. To bad for me :) That means that I cannot use DateTime type to store dates, but rather must fall back to string. (and this is not good for the users..)